# Trigger events in Concourse

Tags: concourse

I'm trying to fire events when a task/resource is executed. Currently the idea is to trigger an event in the script of the task.

As I need the metadata variables (BUILD_ID, BUILD_NAME) as part of the information to be sent in the event, I've created a resource (the only way to access to the metadata) and passed it to the task. **But** the problem is that I cannot access to theses variables in the tasks.

Any idea o strategy to solve this?

Comment: Can you please share some code to understand the structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access data within your resource, you need to pass the resource to the task you are executing.

Check out this example https://gist.github.com/gdenn/91e9d5369f7e0e289960e56cd69e942f

We have the job `demo_job` which holds a resource `some_git_resource` and a task `use_demo_resource_and_do_something`.

In order to let the task access the data inside `some_resource`, you need to declare the resource as input of the task.

You do so by specifying the variable name and path in line 15 & 16.
With the name property you reference the resource name and with the path variable you specify the path for the resource folder in your docker container.

Upload the pipeline and trigger the job. Once it is running use the `fly hijack` command to log into the docker container of the task `use_demo_resource_and_do_something`. You will notice that your container has a folder called `some_git_resource` in the root.

If you only have one input for your task you could also set the path to `.` But keep in mind that this will only work for single inputs. If you want to use multiple inputs in your task, you have to use a proper `path`.

If you have trouble with your scripts inside the tasks, try hijacking the container. Often you get some more insight why your task is not working this way.
To hijack demo_task inside the demo_job use this command `fly -t <your_target> hijack -j demo_job/demo_task`

For further informations checkout the concourse task documentation.

Comment: Thanks Rapdrei. Is there any way to automate that hijack command? Ideally I want to put the eventing as part of the pipeline, currently I have it inside the script using a resource where I collect the metadata and pass it through the task.

Comment: We have a misunderstanding. The hijack command is there to debug your pipeline. You shouldn't use it in your pipeline.

Sometimes it is very useful to see what is going on the docker container in which your tasks is executed.