# task config not found

Tags: continuous-integration, task, concourse

I am getting

> task config 'get-snapshot-jar/infra/hw.yml

not found error. I have written a very simple pipeline .yml, this yml will connect to artifactory resource and run another yml which is defined in task section.

my pipeline.yml looks like:

```
 resources:
- name: get-snapshot-jar
  type: docker-image 
  source: <artifactory source> 
   repository: <artifactory repo> 
   username: {{artifactory-username}}
   password: {{artifactory-password}}

  jobs:
- name: create-artifact
  plan:
  - get: get-snapshot-jar
    trigger: true
  - task: copy-artifact-from-artifact-repo
    file: get-snapshot-jar/infra/hw.yml
```

Artifactiory is working fine after that I am getting an error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6MlB.png)
copy-artifact-from-artifact-repo
task config 'get-snapshot-jar/infra/hw.yml' not found

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an input for your `copy-artifact-from-artifact-repo` task which passes the `get-snapshot-jar` resource to the tasks docker container. Take a look at this post where someone runs into a similar problem [Trigger events in Concourse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882044/trigger-events-in-concourse/45917978#45917978) .

Also your `file` variable looks weird. Your are referencing a docker-image resource which, according to the official concourse-resource github repo, has no yml files inside.

Generally i would keep my task definitions as close as possible to the pipeline code. If you have to reach out to different repos you might loose the overview if your pipeline keeps growing.

cheers,

Comment: Thank you for your response !! I have changed the resources: to my git repo and copied the yml there and it worked fine.